# Running Excel Macro through Access VBA Runtime Error -2147417851

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I created code that will copy the RecordSet to Excel and I want a macro in the Excel file to run. The code works perfectly until it hits the code to run the macro. I must not be calling the application correctly but can't figure it out!

```
Private Sub Command233_Click()
Dim objXLS As Object
 Dim wks As Object
 Dim rsc As Recordset
 Dim idx As Long
 Set rsc = Me.RecordsetClone
If Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0 Then
MsgBox ("No Records To Export")
Else
 rsc.MoveLast
 rsc.MoveFirst
 Set objXLS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 objXLS.Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Comps Macro.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True
 Set wks = objXLS.Worksheets(1)
 For idx = 0 To rsc.Fields.Count - 1
   wks.Cells(1, idx + 1).Value = rsc.Fields(idx).Name
 Next
 wks.Range(wks.Cells(1, 1), wks.Cells(1, rsc.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True
 wks.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsc, rsc.RecordCount, rsc.Fields.Count
 objXLS.Visible = True
 objXLS.Run ("Format")
End If

 Set objXLS = Nothing

End Sub
```

The runtime error I am receiving is:
Run-Time Error '-2147417851 (80010105)':
Method 'Run' of object '_Application' failed

Comment: Does format exist in comps book?

Comment: Yes, I can run the macro manually in the Excel file

Comment: Try adding the filename also in the run call

Comment: Adding the filename like: objXLS.Run ("Comps Macro.xlsm!Format")?

Comment: I think you need 'xyz'!macro.  Not in excel at the minute, so cant get the correct syntax for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the Sub or Function correctly.
Your Sub named `Format` is defined at Workbook- or Sheet- level?

If defined in a Sheet module (for example Sheet1):

```
objXLS.Run ("Sheet1.Format")
```

If at Workbook level:

```
objXLS.Run ("ThisWorkbook.Format")
```

Hope this helps